# Move plus-minus icon on bootstrap accordion to extreme right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to move the plus-minus icon on bootstrap accordion to extreme right position but my code doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the CSS past:

```
.mb-0 > a:before {
        float: right !important;
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        content:"\f068";
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
    .mb-0 > a.collapsed:before {
        float: right !important;
        content:"\f067";
    }
    .mb-0 > a:hover, 
    .mb-0 > a:active, 
    .mb-0 > a:focus  {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
```

And here's the HTML part:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample" style="margin-top: 3%;">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
                <a class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    1. Human Growth and development
                </a>
            </h2>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Bootstrap is a sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want something like the example shown here: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uGe2Z/13/)

Comment: FYI, your fiddle doesn’t show anything useful for me, because my browser blocks all the insecure resources you embedded into a page served over HTTPS there.

Comment: Hi @nick, it seems you have posted 11 questions. All but one has been answered yet you have never accepted an answer. If an answer solves your problem, you should use the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as correct. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Change `padding-right:5px` on `panel-heading`

```
.panel-heading{
  padding-right:3px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/c1f9zr4v/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you use `::after` rather than `::before` to place the icon *after* the text node, you can use a combination of `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between` to position the icon:

```css
.mb-0>a:after {
  float: right !important;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f068";
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.mb-0>a.collapsed:after {
  float: right !important;
  content: "\f067";
}

.mb-0>a:hover,
.mb-0>a:active,
.mb-0>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mb-0>a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample" style="margin-top: 3%;">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <a class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          1. Human Growth and development
        </a>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Bootstrap is a sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If you want to continue using `:before`, you could use `order` to position the icon after the text node:

```css
.mb-0>a:before {
  float: right !important;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f068";
  padding-right: 5px;
  
  order: 2;
}

.mb-0>a.collapsed:before {
  float: right !important;
  content: "\f067";
}

.mb-0>a:hover,
.mb-0>a:active,
.mb-0>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mb-0>a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample" style="margin-top: 3%;">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <a class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          1. Human Growth and development
        </a>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Bootstrap is a sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using display flex, I set the positions of the two elements. 
I added the required classes to collapse only when the plus button was pressed. 
That seems to solve your problem.

```
 Css: 

  #collapse-btn {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
  }

 Html: 

  <h2 class="mb-0">
     <a class="btn btn-link collapsed" id="collapse-btn">
        1. Human Growth and development
        <i class="fas fa-plus" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"></i>
     </a>
  </h2>
```